# Facebook FB.Connect.requireSession() stopped working

Tags: facebook

I've got this page that calls:

```
FB.Connect.requireSession(callback)
```

and in the callback are all the things I need to do after I know the user has a working FB session. It used to pop up a new window, which would ask for permission (or to log in, or whatever) then close and call my callback function. Now, however, it opens a window, asks for permission, and then sends the user to the canvas page on Facebook IN THE POPUP WINDOW. I have no idea what could be going wrong because I'm just using the documented JS apis, and not even doing anything fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the old Javascript SDK which is deprecated, FB.Connect is no longer supported. Use the [new Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and the `FB.Login` [method](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login)

Comment: The old SDK is deprecated, but that doesn't mean that they won't fix the bug.  I suggest you go and comment on the open bug report - http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12260 .

Comment: But if you've just started building an application why would you use deprecated and broken software? Use the new WORKING SDK